# MYSQL ORDER BY alphabetical order not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB with a table full of facility names. I am trying to output the facilities alphabetically by facility name + display the account that it is associated with.

Facilities table looks something like this:

```
id | account_id | facility_name |
 2 |     2      |  Facility A   |
 3 |     2      |  Facility B   |
 4 |     2      |  Facility A   |
```

Accounts table looks like this:

```
account_id | account_name |
    1      |  Account 1   |
    2      |  Account 2   | 
    3      |  Account 3   |
```

And I am trying to get my output to be like this:

```
 facility_name | account_name |
  Facility A   |  Account 1   |
  Facility B   |  Account 1   |
```

I am outputting this into a table using PHP so here is kinda what it looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM facility INNER JOIN account ON account.account_id = facility.account_id WHERE facility.account_id = '". $q ."' ORDER BY 'facility_name'";

echo   "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Facility Name</th>
            <th>Account Name</th>
            </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['facility_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['account_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";
```

However this does not seem to be ordering my table my facility name, it is just outputting in the order that it was input in.

How can I output my data so that it is also ordered by 'facility_name'?

Comment: You're not checking for errors on  your query and it would have thrown you that syntax error that you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
ORDER BY 'facility_name'";
```

You are LITERALLY ordering by the string "facility_name".

Take out the quotes like:

```
ORDER BY facility_name";
```

Comment: Yep, got it, thanks Ill accept this when I can!

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are wrong. It should be just the field name without quotes:

```
ORDER BY facility_name
```

or using backticks (allowed, but only necessary when there are spaces or other special characters in the field name):

```
ORDER BY `facility_name`
```

If you use normal quotes like you do, it will be a string literal, so you are just sorting by the text `'facility_name'`, which has the same constant value for each row, so the sorting doesn't have effect.

Answer (score 0):

Appending this to your query should work:

```
ORDER BY facility_name ASC
```

If not, try putting it inside tick marks like this:

```
ORDER BY `facility_name` ASC
```